# Redirect to login page if session expires from AJAX request

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to perform a redirect when using `@Ajax.ActionLink` to the login page if the user's session has expired instead of the login page loading on the view where the Ajax content would be updated? For example is it possible to check the status received from the server in the `OnBegin` function of the Ajax call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Phil Haack wrote a nice article about this situation and options to handle it: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx

Here is another options where your return object includes a variable to indicate if the result should be redirected, [Why jquery ajax calls fails after session timeout in asp.net mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995315/why-jquery-ajax-calls-fails-after-session-timeout-in-asp-net-mvc).

Comment: The problem with those links are, they are using JQuery Ajax: $.ajax({ }); ... whereas im using @Ajax.ActionLink(...)

Comment: I believe you can use the OnSuccess AjaxOption for the Ajax.ActionLink method to get the same effect.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the responses! I actually got something similar to what I wanted to work by using the OnFaiure AjaxOption and then by doing this in the function: function Failed(response) { var code = response.status; //other code here }

Answer (score 1):

I know this is coming a little late, but just in case another user lands here. My favorite way of handling this is to inherit from and extend the AuthorizeAttribute. That way, I can decorate all controllers that need to redirect Ajax calls to the login page.

It is sleek and re-usable, and actually simpler than most people imagine. There is a complete step by step tutorial on how to do this here: [ASP.NET MVC 4: How to Redirect to Login Page from an AJAX Call with [Authorize]](http://spacehoot.com/Stream/Article/Index/59)

Hope it helps.